# Performance comparison of different activation functions

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, activation-function

I was trying to find a way to compare the test accuracy and test loss of different activation functions (such as tanh, sigmoid, relu), so I came up with this script:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras import models
from keras import layers
import tensorflow as tf 
import keras.backend as K
from tqdm import tqdm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, stratify=y, random_state=42)
train_labels = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train)
test_labels = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test)

def test_activation_functions(act):
    K.clear_session()
    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation=act, input_shape=(4,)))
    model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                    metrics=['accuracy'])
    model.fit(X_train, train_labels, epochs=20, batch_size=40 , verbose=0)
    test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(X_test, test_labels, verbose=0)
    del model
    return test_loss , test_acc

def loop(act, iters):
    test_losses = []
    test_accs = []
    for i in tqdm(range(iters)):
        test_loss , test_acc = test_activation_functions(act)
        test_losses.append(test_loss)
        test_accs.append(test_acc)

    return test_losses , test_accs

def plot_histograms(test_losses, test_accs):
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
    plt.subplot(1,2,1)
    plt.hist(test_losses, bins=20)
    plt.title(f"Average Test Losses {round(np.average(test_losses), 4)}, \n std:{round(np.std(test_losses),4)}")
    plt.subplot(1,2,2)
    plt.hist(test_accs, bins=20)
    plt.title(f"Average Test Accuracy = {round(np.average(test_accs), 4)}, \n std = {round(np.std(test_accs), 4)}")
    plt.show()

def main():
   
    test_losses_relu , test_accs_relu = loop(tf.keras.activations.relu, 1000)
    test_losses_sigmoid , test_accs_sigmoid = loop(tf.keras.activations.sigmoid, 1000)
    test_losses_tanh , test_accs_tanh = loop(tf.keras.activations.tanh, 1000)

    plot_histograms(test_losses_relu, test_accs_relu)
    plot_histograms(test_losses_sigmoid, test_accs_sigmoid)
    plot_histograms(test_losses_tanh, test_accs_tanh)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Before I get to my main question: am I clearing the TensorFlow sessions correctly? or my code can be optimized further?

Now the main question I have is, is this implementation reasonable? For example, here are the results of the loop of 1000 iterations:

ReLU:

[image]

Sigmoid:

[image]

Tanh:

[image]

However, I don't understand why tanh is performing better than relu. (Maybe on a deeper model relu - due to vanishing gradient -  is better than tanh? )

So, Is there a more systematic way to "benchmark" these activation functions?

Comment: Really activation functions like architecture highly depends on the task at hand. So for iris tanh maybe better but this is not an unconditional result.

Comment: Like @NikosM. said depends on the data you have. Tanh has the problem of Vanishing gradient but it can map correctly negative, 0 and positive weights, ReLU only map positive values, other values will be 0. Try Leaky ReLU it allow negative values to be mapped using an alpha parameter. 

Your benchmark seems right to me.